# How to add browsable intent-filters to a dynamic Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: java, android, intentfilter, android-broadcastreceiver, browsable

I'm actually searching for a way to add dynamically some browsable intent-filters to an activity using a Broadcast Receiver, I've made this in my activity :

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Message", "uri "+ intent.getData().getPath());
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    intentF = new IntentFilter();
    intentF.addAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    intentF.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    intentF.addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
    intentF.addDataScheme("http");
    intentF.addDataScheme("https");
    intentF.addDataAuthority("*.google.fr", null);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentF);
}
```

But when I go to  https://google.fr on chrome browser app, I'm not redirected to my app...

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.